# Exporting dump file to postgres database

Tags: nitrousio

In my Nitrous box I use a heroku postgres database as development database. Now I have a data.dump file I want to export to this postgres database. How can I do that, because it is only a database without an app on Heroku, you can't just use a pg_restore command right?

Comment: Which format has your dump? Is it in SQL format (plain text SQL statements) or in the so called "custom dump format" (compressed binary stuff)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, you can use just the normal pg_restore command, but need to change the port in database.yml to 5572 (secure port)